# typeahead.js no errors but not working

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement typeahead but for some reason, it won't show up.

room.js:

```
var data = [];
$.get('url_to_json', function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
});

var students = new Bloodhound({
  limit: 5,
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('global_id'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: data
});

students.initialize();

$('.search_by_name').typeahead({
    highlight: true
  },
  {
    name: 'name_first',
    displayKey: 'global_id',
    source: students.ttAdapter()

  });
```

room.html:

```
<input class="form-control search-by-name" placeholder="Ex: smith1jo / 123456" id="id_search" name="search" type="text">
```

the url that I am accessing is just a django HttpResponse of json in this structure:

```
[
    {
        'global_id': 'value1',
        'name_first': 'value2',
    },
    {
        'global_id': 'value3',
        'name_first': 'value4',
    },
]
```

When I go to the page, the javascript console doesn't throw any errors but the type ahead feature just won't show up. I don't notice a difference.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the source in Dev Tools? Does the typeahead get initialised? Does your `ttAdapter` function get called? What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your code only after the document is ready. Wrap everything in a

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code here
});
```

and it should work.

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XReGImyWkoFJOwvd6t56?p=preview)